# Spring WebFlux and Kotlin Support: How to do Integration Tests?

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/kotlin.html#easy-testing-kotlin-and-junit-5 shows a code sample for an integration test. However I do not understand this line:

```
val application = Application(8181)
```

`8181` should be the port number. But where does `Application` come from? Is this the application class of a *Spring Boot* app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/sdeleuze/spring-kotlin-functional/blob/master/src/test/kotlin/functional/IntegrationTests.kt

The code of the tutorial is contained there. To cut it short: The `Application` is a class of your project, but just checkout the project https://github.com/sdeleuze/spring-kotlin-functional